# Drag and drop in Eclipse Project Explorer is somehow disabled for Java entities

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently, when I try to drag my class to a different package, my mouse pointer shows as crossed circle, and nothing happens when I drop.

In fact, any drag and drop in Project Explorer results in crossed circle and no action.

I tried restarting Eclipse - makes no difference.

Tried to switch between Working Sets and Projects, Flat vs. Hierarchcal - makes no difference.

I use Eclipse Luna.

Anyone seen this before? Anyone knows how to enable Drag-and-drop again?

Update: looks like I cannot drag Java to anywhere and I cannot drag anything into Java packages or Java source folders. Any other drag/drop still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, the answer seems to be "Use Package Explorer, not Project Explorer".

Comment: even package explorer is not draggable